# how to take all non zero elements product of matrix in matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix-multiplication

if I have matrix with all elements have nonzero values then `prod(prod(a))`   works but if some elements of matrix have zero value then `prod(prod(a~=0))`  gives 0 value then how to take all non zero elements product of matrix  in matlab.

Comment: ok prod(prod(a(a~=0))) works

Comment: You only need one `prod` as `a(a~=0)` gives a vector.

Comment: Also `prod(nonzeros(a))`